# How to replace every double occurrence of a char

Tags: c, string

I'm looking for a way to override every occurrence of a double e in a text file and replace it with a * (eg the word been changed to b**n). This is part of a larger function so ignore any of the variables being a weird type that's due to other previous code and my file has to be opened in r+.

```
int maxChar = 101; //ASCII for e
char c = '*';
char line[200];
int i;

File *in_file = fopen(filename, r+);

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), in_file)) {
    for (i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (line[i] == maxChar && line[i + 1] == maxChar) {
            line[i] = c;
            line[i + 1] = c;
            fprintf(in_file, "%s", line);
        }
    }
}
fclose(in_file);
```

Comment: I would make a FSM for this, you have some cases to cover.

Comment: Maybe think about scanning the file one character at a time using fgetc and keeping track of if the last character was an e. If the current character is an e, and the last character flag is set, you can back up the file pointer by two characters using rewind and overwrite those two Es using fputc.

Comment: Do you really need to edit a single file in place or is it acceptable to read from an input file and write to a separate output file?  Would it be acceptable to read the entire file into memory?

Comment: One problem with the code is that it reads 200 characters at a time, independent of line breaks, so if a valid "ee" begins at 200, then only the first "e" would be detected, followed by a second "e" detected on the next loop, none of which detects the "ee" pattern. I like @Kevin suggestion to process one character at a time, keeping a small buffer for detection logic and writing out to the file.